# Why does this case statement need an "if else" and not just an "if"?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

So I am new to C++, and I am working through a pdf tutorial that is getting me started with basic stuff. I was writing a simple case program, and I experienced something weird.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum string_feeling {
    eGood,
    eBad,
    eOk,
};

string_feeling hashit(string const& feeling) {
    if (feeling == "Good" || feeling == "good" || feeling == "GOOD") {
    return eGood;
    }
    if (feeling == "Bad" || feeling == "bad" || feeling == "BAD") {
        return eBad;
    }
    if (feeling == "Ok" || feeling == "ok" || feeling == "OK") {
        return eOk;
    } 
    else cout << "";
}

int main() {
    string username;
    cout << "Hello! Please enter your first name here: \n";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Hello, " << username << "!\n";
    cout << "How are you today? ";
    string feeling;
    cin >> feeling;
    cout << endl;

    switch (hashit(feeling)) {
    case eGood:
        cout << "That's great!";
        break;
    case eBad:
        cout << "I hope you are happy soon!";
        break;
    case eOk:
        cout << "That's good.";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Ok.";
    }
}
```

Whenever I didn't have the "else" after the "if (feeling == ok)" stuff, the default case would never be called and if I entered something random it would give me the text from the eGood case. I was wondering why this is happening and since I'm learning C++ I didn't want to just brush it off not ever knowing why it worked after I put the else statement in there. So, if anyone could explain this to me that would be great! Sorry for my bad grammar.

Comment: Post the code that has the problem, rather than some code which you seem to say works but would have a problem if we edit it according to some instructions given separately.  And remove the code which is not required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: With or without an `else` there, your program has undefined behaviour. You need to `return` or `throw` in every reachable path.

Comment: if you do not want to add a new case in `string_feeling` you can change `hashit` to be for instance `bool hashit(const string & feeling, string_feeling & v)` to return false without setting *v* when *feeling* is in valid, else set *v* and return true

Comment: Note about efficiency of this code's style.  It's might be not vital in this case but one should think of this sometimes. You do three comparisons in each if() statement, which are O(length) in complexity,and worst case your function is O(9*length). Uppercase the string first (can it be "gOOd"?) and you get O(4*length) at worst, or do pattern comparison which would be O(length) in worst case for whole function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When none of conditions in the three `if` statements in `hashit` function become true, no `return` statement is executed in the function and *undefined behavior* is invoked.

(Quote from [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.6.3 The return statement)

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

To avoid this, you should add one more kind to the `enum`

```
enum string_feeling {
    eGood,
    eBad,
    eOk,
    eOther // add this
};
```

and return it when no conditions are met.

```
string_feeling hashit(string const& feeling) {
    if (feeling == "Good" || feeling == "good" || feeling == "GOOD") {
    return eGood;
    }
    if (feeling == "Bad" || feeling == "bad" || feeling == "BAD") {
        return eBad;
    }
    if (feeling == "Ok" || feeling == "ok" || feeling == "OK") {
        return eOk;
    } 
    else cout << "";
    return eOther; // add this
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Compile your program with warnings enabled like `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror` and it won't even compile, because `string_feeling hashit(string const& feeling)` does not return a value in all cases.

Compiling code without warnings enabled is a surefire way to waste time.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to return a value else the behavior is undefined

If you cannot modify your enum to add a case for an unknown feeling you can modify *hashit* to return true if *feeling* is valid and in that case to set the output parameter with the corresponding enum value, else to return false without setting the output parameter :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum string_feeling {
    eGood,
    eBad,
    eOk,
};

bool hashit(string const& feeling, string_feeling & r) {
  if (feeling == "Good" || feeling == "good" || feeling == "GOOD") {
    r = eGood;
  }
  else if (feeling == "Bad" || feeling == "bad" || feeling == "BAD") {
    r = eBad;
  }
  else if (feeling == "Ok" || feeling == "ok" || feeling == "OK") {
    r = eOk;
  } 
  else
    return false;
  
  return true;
}

int main() {
    string username;
    cout << "Hello! Please enter your first name here: \n";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Hello, " << username << "!\n";
    cout << "How are you today? ";
    string feeling;
    cin >> feeling;
    cout << endl;
    
    string_feeling f;
    
    if (! hashit(feeling, f))
      cout << "I do not understand how you are" << endl;
    else {
      switch (f) {
      case eGood:
        cout << "That's great!" << endl;
        break;
      case eBad:
        cout << "I hope you are happy soon!" << endl;
        break;
      case eOk:
        cout << "That's good." << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Hello! Please enter your first name here: 
bruno
Hello, bruno!
How are you today? good

That's great!
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Hello! Please enter your first name here: 
bruno
Hello, bruno!
How are you today? aze

I do not understand how you are
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Out of that :

- to name your enum `string_feeling` is not very clear, whatever  the feeling was input as a string, better to just name it *Feeling*
- it can be practical in *hashit* to get the string by value to change it to lowercase then to just compare it with with "good" "bad" and "ok" or to use `strcasecmp` on its `.c_str()`, allowing to also manage "gOoD" etc

Answer (score 0):

If no `if` conditions will meet, `hashit` went to

```c
else cout << "";
```

Since you didn't explicitly write the `return` statement, the function returns the default value `0`, which is equal to `eGood`.

However, the default return value is not always `0`. This is an `undefined behaviour`.

If you runs this code with a different compiler, you `may` get different results.

Comment: _"the function returns the default value 0"_ ... _"However, the default return value is not always 0"_ That's somewhat contradictory.